# How to convert powershell onliner to PS1

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell one liner that would like to transform on a PS1 file

This question is pretty basic but how do I convert apowershell one liner to PS1?

Thanks

Comment: it depends on how you want to use it. [*grin*] if you just want to run it ... simply save it as a `.ps1` file. if you want to enable it to accept parameters, you will need to add a way to get parameters into your code. look up advanced functions for some examples of the basic idea.

Comment: Thank you for the help. This is what Im looking for.

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to help a little ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

There are a few steps to do this:

- Open notepad.
- Copy and paste the powershell script into notepad. Now if the one-liner has multiple lines using `;` separate them by using enter. You can expand The for, if, while, try blocks like this:

```
try
{
  Anything
}
```

You can also make the script accept args using $args automatic variable. $args[0], $args[1] .. $args[n] parameters and so on.

- Select file menu and save as dialog.
- Enter the name of powershell script with extension .ps1 (Example: foo.ps1).
- Choose "All files" in the drop down menu.
- Click save button. Here you go!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It will be very useful for future projects :)